# Excel VBA create name from two different ranges to be used in list (data validation)

Tags: excel, vba, list, names

Is it possible to create one name from two different ranges to be used in list (data validation)?

I have two columns: **A** which has content from rows 1 to 3 and **C** which has content from rows 1 to 4.

I tried using `ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="TheList", RefersTo:=Range("A1:A3,C1:C4")` but when inserting `=TheList` in the data validation field, it says "The list source must be a delimited list, or a reference to a single row or column".

Is there a way to combine the values from both columns?

Comment: The range for a data validation list needs to be contiguous. You can solve this by setting up a contiguous list in a different column. For example starting in D1, you can enter `=A1`, then `D2=A2`, `D3=A3`, `D4=C1`, etc. Add your named range for the range `D1:D6` and it should work.

Comment: @PeterT Is it possible to do that using VBA? I really don't want to create another column because it's a form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Excel requires a contiguous range of values to be used as a data validation list, you really have two options.

1. Create a separate (possibly linked), contiguous column of values in an unused area of the workbook. Adding a defined name for the range is suggested, but not required.

For this method, I'd build up a list way out in the "Z" column (or possibly in another, hidden worksheet). Here's an example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub MakeValidationRange()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim dataRange As Range
    Set dataRange = ws.Range("A1:A3,C1:C3")

    Dim valRange As Range
    Set valRange = ws.Range("Z1")

    Dim entry As Variant
    For Each entry In dataRange
        valRange.Formula = "=" & entry.Address
        Set valRange = valRange.Offset(1, 0)
    Next entry
    Set valRange = ws.Range("Z1").CurrentRegion

    '--- alternate method using a named range
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="TheList", RefersTo:=valRange

    Dim dropDownCell As Range
    Set dropDownCell = ws.Range("B1")
    dropDownCell.Validation.Delete
    dropDownCell.Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
                                AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                                Formula1:="=TheList"

    '--- alternate method without creating a named range
    Set dropDownCell = ws.Range("B2")
    dropDownCell.Validation.Delete
    dropDownCell.Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
                                AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                                Formula1:="=(" & valRange.Address & ")"

End Sub
```

2. The second method is to not use another range at all, just create a delimited list. This makes the list "hard-coded", but since it's created with VBA that may not be a hindrance in your case.

The key in this one lies in defining the list to the `.Validation.Add` method **without** an equals sign. For example, the validation list would be `Red,Orange,Yellow,Green,Blue,Indigo,Violet`. No double quotes. No spaces. No equals. Here's the example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub MakeValidationList()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim dataRange As Range
    Set dataRange = ws.Range("A1:A3,C1:C3")

    Dim dataList As String
    Dim entry As Variant
    For Each entry In dataRange
        dataList = dataList & entry.Value & ","
    Next entry
    '--- remove the last trailing comma
    dataList = Left$(dataList, Len(dataList) - 1)

    Dim dropDownCell As Range
    Set dropDownCell = ws.Range("B3")
    dropDownCell.Validation.Delete
    dropDownCell.Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
                                AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                                Formula1:=dataList
End Sub
```

Comment: Great, exactly what I need! I went for the second method. However, if I change the value of any cell, it will continuously add again without deleting the previous list. Seems like `dropDownCell.Validation.Delete` is not working :\

Comment: I added `dataList = ""` before the `For Each entry` to clear the contents. Is this the right way? At least it's working properly now :P

Comment: If you're in a loop, yes that's one of the best ways to clear a string. The other would be `dataList = vbNullString`.